# Displaying Google map in min Latitude/Longitude to max Latitude/Longitude

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried to display the Google map only from min Latitude/Longitude to max Latitude/Longitude on the device screen. What I did is get max and min of latitude and longitude and display as

```
map.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)((maxLatitude + minLatitude)/2),(int)((maxLongitude + minLongitude)/2 )));
```

But it does not work. This line has compile error for "The method animateTo(GeoPoint) is undefined for the type GoogleMap". What is wrong?

Comment: I am using Google Maps Android API v2. Thanks

Comment: GeoPoint is from API v1

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach and it works.

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelp.fetchAllLatLongInTheList();
    LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        latitude = latitudelongitudeConverter(cursor.getString(3));
        longitude = latitudelongitudeConverter(cursor.getString(4));
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        bld.include(ll); 
    }
```